# Use 'sed' or other similar command to capture a group and then only output that data

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have a log file that looks like the following:

```
 sdfsdf
 sdfsdf<Pay>1234</Pay> sdfsdfsdf
 sdfsdf<Pay>12342323</Pay> sdfsdfsdf
 sdfsdf
```

...
I only want to print out:

```
1234
12342323
```

I was considering using 'sed' and have the following line:

```
sed 's/<Pay>(*)<\/Pay>/\1/g' abc.txt
```

But I get the error:

sed: -e expression #1, char 22: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

How can I achieve the desired output?

This is with Ubuntu Linux latest, bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -n 's/.*<Pay>\(.*\)<\/Pay>.*/\1/p' file
```

Comment: Won't work if there's more than one Pay per line, but works for the given input.

Comment: Correct. It won't work for other inputs that are different from the posted input either such as the `</Pay>` being on a different line from the `<Pay>` or `<Pay>` taking arguments like `<Pay height=3>` or ....

Answer (score 2):

Perfect case for `grep -o`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=<Pay>).+?(?=</Pay>)'
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed`, contrary to Perl, needs escaping for its capturing parentheses: `\(.*\)`

Too get your expected output, you'll then need to get rid of the rest of the line. Just include it in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` (only `gawk` or `mawk` due to regex in RS)

```
awk 'NR%2==0' RS="</?Pay>" file
1234
12342323
```